# WAMP Server New VHost domain not accessable

Tags: apache, localhost, wamp, local, vhosts

So I added a new vhost, **api.tessitura.com** to my apache client within the WAMP server installed on my local box where I have 2 other vhost sites running.  Modified my hosts file so I can access it locally, however I'm getting a 403 Forbidden "You don't have permission to access / on this server." Error when I load the site.  The pre-existing vhost sites are totally fine and accessible.  I've restarted my WAMP client, not sure what the problem could be.

Here is my http-vhosts.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName tessitura.local.com
    ServerAlias tessitura.local.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/dev/sites/tessitura.local.com"

    <Directory "c:/dev/sites/tessitura.local.com">
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName api.tessitura.com
    ServerAlias api.tessitura.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/dev/sites/api.tessitura.com"

    <Directory "c:/dev/sites/api.tessitura.com">
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

#LOCAL

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www" 
    ServerName localhost 
    ServerAlias localhost 
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How is the domain resolved in DNS? Did you modified you local hosts file or is it a real DNS name in your network wich resolves to your apache server?

Comment: modified my local hosts file

Comment: And the hosts entry looks like this?

`127.0.0.1       api.tessitura.com`

Comment: You have already checked the following?
 Access Right for http-user in the directory, index.html exists oder Indexes option is set. there is no .htaccess file which prevents access

Comment: yes the hostfile is correct.  permissions are good.  index.php exists, if I enable "Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews" I get the list of directories and files on the vhost, but the index.php isn't shown, which may be a sign of the problem.  There is not an htaccess file.

Comment: So it looks like the php file handler is not registered / activated. Maybe you just create a simple `index.html`to verify the vhosts file itself. Because it sounds like the vhost itself is working. Afterwards you can analyse the issue with the index.php

Comment: the index.php was just a blank file.  I added some basic code, restarted the server and it worked after that.  Strange never had that issue before.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: [This post may help you to setup VHOST properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)